# Selenium Webdriver Switch/Case c#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, switch-statement, case

```
    [When(@"I click the Login button")]
    public void WhenIClickTheLoginButton()
    {
        _driver.Click(ElementType.Id, VariableList.LoginButtonId); //Clicks login button first

        string currentUrl = _driver.Url;

        if (currentUrl == BaseUrls.HomepageUk)
        {
            _driver.AssertIsTrueByUrl(_driver.Url, BaseUrls.HomepageUk);
        }
        if (currentUrl == BaseUrls.LogonPageUk) //Takes into account erroneous login
        {
            _driver.AssertIsTrueByUrl(_driver.Url, BaseUrls.LogonPageUk);
        }
        if (currentUrl == BaseUrls.PromoPageUk) //Takes into account the possibility of a promotion being displayed
        {
            _driver.AssertIsTrueByUrl(_driver.Url, BaseUrls.PromoPageUk);
            _driver.WaitForElementPresent(ElementType.Id, VariableList.PromoBanner);
            _driver.AssertElementDisplayed(ElementType.Id, VariableList.PromoBanner);
            _driver.AssertElementDisplayed(ElementType.XPath, VariableList.ContinueToHomepageButton);
            _driver.Click(ElementType.XPath, VariableList.ContinueToHomepageButton);
        }
    }
```

I'm struggling to change this into a case/switch statement rather than using multiple if statements. I have a similar login method multiple times.

Comment: Sounds like refactoring thing. Take a look at codreview.stackexchange.com. Though it's not clear what can went wrong with replacing these ifs with `switch(currentUrl)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translating `if` statements into a `switch` should be pretty straightforward after reading some tutorials. BUT... you've got some logic issues in your `if` statements that I think should be cleaned up and simplified before doing so.

An example:

```
if (currentUrl == BaseUrls.HomepageUk)
{
    _driver.AssertIsTrueByUrl(_driver.Url, BaseUrls.HomepageUk);
}
```

When is the above Assert going to fail? It won't. You've already essentially done the assert by comparing the URLs so there's really no need for that assert, or the next one, or the next one. What you want instead is to verify that the current URL is in the list of 3 URLs. You can do this with a `switch` like

```
[When(@"I click the Login button")]
public void WhenIClickTheLoginButton()
{
    _driver.Click(ElementType.Id, VariableList.LoginButtonId); //Clicks login button first

    switch (_driver.Url)
    {
        case BaseUrls.HomepageUk:
            break;
        case BaseUrls.LogonPageUk:
            break;
        case BaseUrls.PromoPageUk:
            _driver.WaitForElementPresent(ElementType.Id, VariableList.PromoBanner);
            _driver.AssertElementDisplayed(ElementType.Id, VariableList.PromoBanner);
            _driver.AssertElementDisplayed(ElementType.XPath, VariableList.ContinueToHomepageButton);
            _driver.Click(ElementType.XPath, VariableList.ContinueToHomepageButton);
            break;
        default:
            // some assert that the URL is not one of the acceptable three
            break;
    }
}
```

The important case that you were missing is the case that would actually cause a failure. What if the URL doesn't match one of the three? Your `if`s don't cover that and that's where the `default` case comes in on the `switch`. The `default` case covers if the comparison doesn't match *any* of the cases.

So the way this works is the login button is clicked and we arrive on the next page. We grab the URL and compare it to two of the URLs. If it matches either of those we break out of the switch doing nothing. If it matches `BaseUrls.PromoPageUk` then we do the steps required. Notice that we don't assert in any of these three cases because there is no need. We know the test would pass. Now we come to the `default` case. If the URL doesn't match one of the above 3, then we need some assert to fail because we landed on an unexpected page. I put a comment placeholder because you aren't using `NUnit` or any test framework that I'm familiar with so I don't know how you would code that assert in your framework.

---

Here's some other advice that you didn't ask for... :)

1. You really should be using `NUnit` or some other standard library. I can tell you aren't using a standard library because asserts shouldn't be hanging off of `_driver` references. Grab NUnit out of NuGet, install it, and use it. It comes with all the assert comparisons you will need. You don't need to write and test your own assert code and there's no need since it's established and used by LOTS of people.
2. I'm generally not a big fan of generic methods like `Click()` for a lot of reasons but if you are going to have one, at least pass in a `By` locator so you don't have to pass in the type of locator and the locator. It will make your life a lot easier for this and other methods you write. For example

   ```
   public static void Click(By locator)
   {
       _driver.FindElement(locator).Click();
   }
   ```

   Your `VariableList` class would look like

   ```
   public static class VariableList
   {
       public static By LoginButtonId = By.Id("whateverTheIdIs");
   }
   ```

   and you would call it like

   ```
   _driver.Click(VariableList.LoginButtonId)
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps

```
switch (currentUrl)
{
    case BaseUrls.HomepageUk
        _driver.AssertIsTrueByUrl(_driver.Url, BaseUrls.HomepageUk);
        break;
    case BaseUrls.LogonPageUk
        _driver.AssertIsTrueByUrl(_driver.Url, BaseUrls.LogonPageUk);
        break;
    case BaseUrls.PromoPageUk
        _driver.AssertIsTrueByUrl(_driver.Url, BaseUrls.PromoPageUk);
        _driver.WaitForElementPresent(ElementType.Id, VariableList.PromoBanner);
        _driver.AssertElementDisplayed(ElementType.Id, VariableList.PromoBanner);
        _driver.AssertElementDisplayed(ElementType.XPath, VariableList.ContinueToHomepageButton);
        _driver.Click(ElementType.XPath, VariableList.ContinueToHomepageButton);
        break;
}
```